# Concise way to filter data in xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I need to apply a very simple 'match statement' to the values in an xarray array:

1. Where the value > 0, make 2
2. Where the value == 0, make 0
3. Where the value is `NaN`, make `NaN`

Here's my current solution. I'm using `NaN`s, `.fillna`, & type coercion in lieu of 2d indexing.

```
valid = date_by_items.notnull()
positive = date_by_items > 0
positive = positive * 2
result = positive.fillna(0.).where(valid)
result
```

This changes this:

```
In [20]: date_by_items = xr.DataArray(np.asarray((list(range(3)) * 10)).reshape(6,5), dims=('date','item'))
    ...: date_by_items
    ...: 
Out[20]: 
<xarray.DataArray (date: 6, item: 5)>
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
  * item     (item) int64 0 1 2 3 4
```

... to this:

```
Out[22]: 
<xarray.DataArray (date: 6, item: 5)>
array([[ 0.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  2.]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
  * item     (item) int64 0 1 2 3 4
```

While in pandas `df[df>0] = 2` would be enough. Surely I'm doing something pedestrian and there's an terser way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

xarray now supports `.where(condition, other)`, so this is now valid:

```
result = date_by_items.where(date_by_items > 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are happy to load your data in-memory as a NumPy array, you can modify the DataArray values in place with NumPy:

```
date_by_items.values[date_by_items.values > 0] = 2
```

The cleanest way to handle this would be if xarray supported the `other` argument to `where`, but we haven't implemented that yet (hopefully soon -- the groundwork has been laid!). When that works, you'll be able to write `date_by_items.where(date_by_items > 0, 2)`.

Either way, you'll need to do this twice to apply both your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Another concise way would be to do `date_by_items.values[date_by_items.values > 0] = 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`where(condition, other)` method](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) indeed. But be aware that the `other` argument will be used **where the condition is false**. So the behavior in the other answers is incorrect, as they will put a 2 where `date_by_items > 0` does **not** hold.

```py
>>> date = list(range(0,6))
>>> item = list(range(0,5))
>>> date_by_items = xr.DataArray(np.asarray((list(range(3)) * 10)).reshape(6,5), coords=[date, item], dims=('date','item'))
>>> date_by_items
<xarray.DataArray (date: 6, item: 5)>
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
  * item     (item) int64 0 1 2 3 4


>>> date_by_items.where(date_by_items > 0, 2)  # wrong behavior
<xarray.DataArray (date: 6, item: 5)>
array([[2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
  * item     (item) int64 0 1 2 3 4
```

Instead, when you want the requested behavior, you either have to invert the condition or use the [`xarray.where(condition, x, y)` method](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.where.html) instead.

```py
>>> date_by_items.where(date_by_items <= 0, 2)  # inverted condition
<xarray.DataArray (date: 6, item: 5)>
array([[0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
  * item     (item) int64 0 1 2 3 4

>>> xarray.where(date_by_items > 0, 2, date_by_items)
<xarray.DataArray (date: 6, item: 5)>
array([[0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
  * item     (item) int64 0 1 2 3 4
```