# boolean indexing in xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have some arrays with dims `'time', 'lat', 'lon'` and some with just `'lat', 'lon'`. I often have to do this in order to mask time-dependent data with a 2d (lat-lon) mask:

```
x.data[:, mask.data] = np.nan
```

Of course, computations broadcast as expected. If `y` is 2d lat-lon data, its values are broadcast to all time coordinates in x:

```
z = x + y
```

But indexing doesn't broadcast as I'd expect. I'd like to be able to do this, but it raises *ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions*:

```
x[mask] = np.nan
```

Lastly, it seems that `xr.where` *does* broadcast the values of the mask across time coordinates as expected, but you can't set values this way.

```
x_masked = x.where(mask)
```

So, is there something I'm missing here that facilitates setting values using a boolean mask that is missing dimensions (and needs to be broadcast)? Is the option I provided at the top really the way to do this (in which case, I might as well just be using standard numpy arrays...)

Comment: Could you add some example data to the question? It would make understanding the requirements much easier and provide some data for the answerers to work with.

Answer (score 10):

Edit: this question is still getting upvotes, but it's now *much* easier - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49442830/3064736)

---

Somewhat related question here: [Concise way to filter data in xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884283/concise-way-to-filter-data-in-xarray)

Currently the best approach is a combination of `.where` and `.fillna`.

```
valid = date_by_items.notnull()
positive = date_by_items > 0
positive = positive * 2
result = positive.fillna(0.).where(valid)
result
```

But changes are coming in xarray that will make this more concise - checkout the GitHub repo if you're interested

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, and glad to hear updates are actively coming!

Comment: Are those changes live in xarray 0.8.2?